# Timelion in Kiabana with ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, timelion

I have garbage collector events data in kibana, and i need to do the following:
Make a line graph which will include the duration of every garbage collection event.
Here is the Json:

```
    {
  "_index": "brain_sys-2017.04.24",
  "_type": "java_gc_log",
  "_id": "AVufE99vjvbJ-WSoGT9K",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "gc_cpu_time_sys": 0,
    "gc_young_usage_before_collection": 42033,
    "gc_heap_before_collection": 275694,
    "gc_young_usage_after_collection": 928,
    "gc_event_time_stamp": "2017-04-24T08:28:43.865+0000",
    "source": "/apps/brain/logs/gc.log.0.current",
    "type": "java_gc_log",
    "event_timestamp": "2017-04-24T08:28:43.865Z",
    "elastic_insert_time": "2017-04-24T08:28:51.437Z",
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "gate06.prod.bos.credorax.com",
      "name": "gate06.prod.bos.credorax.com",
      "version": "5.1.1"
    },
    "@version": "1",
    "gc_heap_after_collection": 235009,
    "gc_duration_in_seconds": 0.00717,
    "offset": 52096,
    "gc_cpu_time_real": 0.01,
    "input_type": "log",
    "gc_heap_total": 388608,
    "message": "2017-04-24T08:28:43.865+0000: 1884391.587: [GC [PSYoungGen: 42033K->928K(41984K)] 275694K->235009K(388608K), 0.0071700 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] ",
    "gc_young": "PSYoungGen",
    "tags": [
      "filebeat",
      "bos"
    ],
    "gc_cpu_time_user": 0.05,
    "@timestamp": "2017-04-24T08:28:46.715Z",
    "gc_young_total_size_after_collection": 41984,
    "gc_relative_to_jvm_time_stamp": 1884391.587,
    "gc_type": "GC"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1493022526715
    ],
    "elastic_insert_time": [
      1493022531437
    ],
    "gc_event_time_stamp": [
      1493022523865
    ],
    "event_timestamp": [
      1493022523865
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1493022523865
  ]
}
```

I need to use the event_timestamp and gc_duration_in_seconds.
I also wish to split it to beat.hostname and by gc_type (GC or GC Full)

Tried this:
.es(index=brain_sys*, 'beat.name'='gate06.prod.fra.credorax.com')
as a start, doesn't really work.

The reason that i am doing this in TimeLion and not as regular visualization is because in need to put on top of that another graph (TPS).

Comment: You need to use the query with `q="beat.name: \"gate...\""`, not the format you put there. You can use then `split: beat.hostname` to separate by hostname and then you can have two queries to filter by gc and gc_full (with `.es(...),.es(...)`).

Comment: Tried what you suggested, much better..es(index=brain_sys*, q="gc_type:GC", metric=avg:gc_duration_in_seconds) but i want to see every GC event that occurs and not average, how can this be achieved ?

Comment: I guess if you select a small enough bucket you can probably achieve what you want.